# JavaScript onclick handlers in quotes giving different behavior?

Tags: javascript

I noticed this odd behavior while writing some demonstration code today, and I'm curious what's happening. "Button" does not work although "Button 2" does, even though they're being set in just different ways. I know it has to do with the quoting, but I'm curious why this is happening. Similarly, if I pass in a function to button 3 in quotes vs appending it directly in button 4, button 4 works but button 3 doesn't.

Also, I would think that given that button 2 works, it would do the evaluation of `console.log("test")` immediately (similar to how it would work without the quotes) but rather it delays until actually clicking on the button. I know this is not the best way to do it but for curiosity sake, I'm curious what's happening exactly here.

```js
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>Testing Sandbox</h1>
<div>
  <button id='hello'>Button</button>
  <button id='hello2' onclick='console.log("test")'>Button 2</button>
  <button id='hello3' onclick='(e) => console.log("test")'>Button 3</button>
  <button id='hello4'>Button 4</button>

</div>
`;

document.getElementById("hello").onclick = 'console.log("test")';
document.getElementById("hello4").onclick = (e) => console.log("test");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>

 <script src="src/index.js">
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("hello").onclick` expects a function whereas you're assigning string

Comment: @CodeManiac, sure that makes sense, but then by that logic Button 2 should not work.

Comment: those two are different contexts one is HTML and another one is JS, why you think both should be same, values assigned to `onClick=` inside html is considered as script, and since `console.log()` is valid script so it gives you `test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign to `onclick`, you invoke a setter, which does something pretty similar to calling `addEventListener` with the assigned expression. But both `addEventListener` and `onclick` will silently fail if the passed expression is not a function:

```js
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>Testing Sandbox</h1>
<div>
  <button id='hello'>Button</button>
`;

document.getElementById("hello").onclick = 'console.log("test")';
// nearly the same thing as:
document.getElementById("hello").addEventListener('click', 'console.log("test")');
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

The string does not get implicitly coerced to a function.

In the third example, the inline handler declares a function, but never executes it:

```
<button id='hello3' onclick='(e) => console.log("test")'>Button 3</button>
```

which is like

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  (e) => console.log("test")
});
```

The listener runs, but the listener doesn't contain anything other than an unused function expression, so you don't see anything when you click. This might be clearer if you add a log statement:

```html
<button id='hello3' onclick='console.log("listener running;"); (e) => console.log("test")'>Button 3</button>
```

In general, you should *never* use inline handlers; they require global pollution, are hard to manage, have string and HTML escaping issues, and are pretty much universally considered to be bad practice. Instead, use `addEventListener`, and always pass it *functions*, not strings, for a listener to be properly added.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This definitely answers my question about 3 and 4. Now regarding button and button 2, I'm still not sure why the inline `onclick` handler is coercing the string into a function but by doing `getElementId` and setting the `onclick` that way gives a different result (silent failure). Also, I would think that `onclick='console.log("hello")'` would evaluate immediately if it's coerced to a function. I certainly agree that I would never do this in practice, but I'm trying to better understand what JS is doing under the hood.

Comment: HTML attributes are always essentially strings (possibly unquoted, if they contain only a certain few characters and no spaces), but assigning to `onclick` (programatically, in Javascript - no attributes involved) invokes a setter, as described in the first part of the answer, and adding listeners via Javascript requires *functions* to be passed

Comment: If you want to more closely emulate having an `onclick` attribute, use `setAttribute` instead of assigning to the `onclick` property (which will invoke the setter)

Comment: I think I see now. If I do `<button id='hello' onclick=console.log("Hello")>Button</button>` then this will execute immediately, but `onclick='console.log("Hello")'` will convert to a function containing what's in the string as you described in your answer. So would it be correct to say that JavaScript takes the string in an inline `onclick` handler and wraps it in a function and coerces the internals to executable JS code, and by invoking the setter, it doesn't do this coercion but rather fails silently if what's passed to the setter is not a function.

Comment: Yeah, with inline handlers, it does something similar to `new Function` or `eval` to transform the attribute string into a JS function

Comment: Gotcha, although wouldn't it be more like `new Function` rather than `eval` since `eval` would evaluate it immediately upon running `eval`, while `new Function` will wrap it and not run until the stored function is called?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the process is, if it actually turns the attribute into a (persistent) function, or whether it just evaluates the containing code when clicked

Comment: @CertainPerformance it seems it just evaluated when the containing code is clicked, [`HTML spec`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

**Why button two works ?**

> It is possible to associate an action with a certain number of events
>   that occur when a user interacts with a user agent. Each of the
>   "intrinsic events" listed above takes a value that is a script. The
>   script is executed whenever the event occurs for that element. The
>   syntax of script data depends on the scripting language.  [`HTML Specs`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3)

So `onclick = script [CT]` will be called whenever user interacts, in this case it is an mouse click event

**Why button don't work ?**

`document.getElementById("hello").onclick` expects a function where as you're passing string